# @Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, code-first

buen dia.
Actualmente estoy trabajando con .net y tengo problema quiero enviar informacion a un metodo de un controlador por medio de un **@Html.ActionLink**, este metodo me pide dos valores los cuales son el **LevelId** que no tengo problema en pasarlo y tengo que pasarle la seleccion que tenga en  *@Html.DropDownList* el problema es que no he podido saber como pasarle la informacion. He intentado colocarle un id *@Html.DropDownList* pero no funciona ya que el **@Html.ActionLink** no lo encuentra.

Este es el *@Html.DropDownList*

```
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group">
    <h3>Anno lectivo</h3>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("AnnoLectivoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" , @id = "AnnoLectivoId" })           
    </div>
</div>
```

El table muestra una informacion y por cada fila existe un **@Html.ActionLink** que permite dirigir a esta informacion a un metodo en un controlador, quiero anexarle la informacion del *@Html.DropDownList* que seria el id de lo que esta seleccionado.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NameLevel)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DescriptionLevel)
    </th>
    <th>
        Acciones
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameLevel)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DescriptionLevel)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Detalle", "ChangeStatus", "Enroll_Student", new { id = item.LevelId }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres tomar un valor de forma dinamica en un ActionLink vas a tener que usar javascript o mejor jquery

```
@Html.ActionLink("Detalle", "ChangeStatus", "Enroll_Student",
                   new { id = item.LevelId,  AnnoLectivo = "param1"}, new { @class = "btn btn-info", id="detalle" })
```

Valida como se definen los parametros que luego se debe reemplazar

```
<script>
    $(function(){

       $("#detalle").click(function(){ 

           val AnnoLectivo = $("#AnnoLectivoId").val();

           this.href = this.href.replace("param1", AnnoLectivo);
       })
    })

</script>
```

Aunque seria mas facil si realizas un submit y pasas los valores como parte del body del form

[ASP.Net MVC: Pass (Send) DropDownList Selected Value to Controller using Html.ActionLink](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Pass-Send-DropDownList-Selected-Value-to-Controller-using-HtmlActionLink.aspx)

Comment: he intentado hacerlo con jquery pero solo trae la informacion del boton del primer elemento los demas no funciona. sabes depronto por que pasa esto.

Comment: puede ser un tema del selector, porque veo que defines dentro de una lista, quizas debas definir  new { @class = "btn btn-info detalle"} y usar la seleccion por class $(".detalle"), en lugar de seleccionar por id usando # usas el . (punto) para seleccionar por el class

Comment: usando el $(".detalle") no me funciona

Comment: que significa que no funciona? no ejecuta el evento. Es cuestion de definir bien el selector de jquery, quizas debas ir desde la table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676924/jquery-select-an-element-inside-a-td se podria probar de seleccionar la tabla y en esta aplicar el class del link

Comment: Gracias ya logre ejecutar el evento quisiera hacerte una pregunta este codigo this.href = this.href.replace("param1", AnnoLectivo); permite reemplazar "param1" por el id verdad? no me funciona existe otra forma de pasarle el id una vez lo tenga en javascript

Comment: lo que deberia hacer es reemplazar en la url el valor de param1 que defines en el ActionLink por el valor seleccionado value seleccionado del combo